# Why does my <div> not expand to height:100%?

Tags: css, height, html

I have 3 divs that correspond to this.
I have #wrapper which wraps around everything. That is #EEE
I have #contain which is inside #wrapper right after. That is #FFF (part with the content)
I have #secondaryContent which is height:100% perfectly fine, position:fixed. which is inside both of those divs.

I added borders to all the main divs to see what's up.

Okay so, the bottom of the middle div is supposed to extend to the bottom at 100% showing no grey from the wrapper. If you look closely at the top of the page You can see a purple line. That's actually a div called #content, which is supposed to have all of the posts in it. I don't know what it's showing as if there's nothing in it but it should  //(* fixed * - see second answer).

You can see what I mean via my server.

[Server](http://74.59.118.85:8888/)

FIX***
the class '.container' that is applied to the #wrapper div is what screwed everything up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a class called 'container' that is applied to the div 'wrapper'. This class container is from a different stylesheet provided by the Habari CMS I use. By removing this class from the div, the height now expands to the document window.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is because there are floats in the #Content div.

You can add this class "hasFloats" to both your css file and in the #content div as well.

**UPDATED**

```
.hasFloats { _height: 1%; }

.hasFloats:after { content: "."; visibility: hidden; display: block; clear: both; height: 0; font-size: 0; }

<div id="content" class="hasFloats">
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Although, that did solve my #content div not expanding issue, it didn't solve my main issue :[

Really helped though!
I wish I could vote you up, but apparently I can't.

btw. Is it actually '_height:1%' ? What does the  '_' do?

Comment: Glad that it helped. whats your main issue?

Comment: My main issue is this: http://www.grabup.com/uploads/ccef44fbf9e2bbea894c925c944f43a2.png  The white part is not expanding all the way to '100%' of the window. Like the sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your `body` to have a `height: 100%` otherwise it will not take up the full screen.

EDIT: Sorry I answered before viewing the site. If it's not taking up the full height have you checked for excess `margin` or `padding`?

Comment: I have not found any excess margin and padding. That was the first thing I looked for. Although, I'm human I might have missed something. I don't think that's quite it.

Comment: Actually I think you have to let html {height: 100%; }. At least for IE7

Comment: You don't have to specify a height! It will automatically expand with content.

Comment: Well, obviously I did for my #secondaryContent sidebar.<br />
Also, html height:100% does not solve this. already tried it.<br />
<a href="http://www.grabup.com/uploads/690262737061f634b9c22713cf77dabe.png">http://www.grabup.com/uploads/690262737061f634b9c22713cf77dabe.png</a>

Comment: Well, obviously I did for my #secondaryContent sidebar. Also, html height:100% does not solve this. already tried it. http://www.grabup.com/uploads/690262737061f634b9c22713cf77dabe.png